# Stop rebuilding when using FutureProviderFamily

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-isar

I have a Flutter app which uses `FutureProviderFamily` to fetch List of items from an `Isar` database.

```
final FutureProviderFamily<List<Card>, Card> searchCardProvider =
    FutureProvider.family(
  (FutureProviderRef<List<Card>> ref, Card card) async {
    final CardUtil cardUtil = await ref.watch(cardUtilProvider.future);
    return cardUtil.search(card);
  },
);
```

The usage is as follows in the page:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ref
      .watch(
        searchCardProvider(
          card.Card()
            ..name = _searchText
            ..cardType = _cardType,
        ),
      )
      .when(...);
```

The page itself has a `SegmentedButton` which holds card types and a `TextFormField` which acts as a search. The values of these items are passed to the provider.

My problem here is the build method re-runs over and over again. I have tried to use the `select` function but couldn't figure out how to use it for a List. Maybe there is a better way to handle this. Any suggestions?

P.S: Another `FutureProvider` that lists out all the data works perfectly, but unable to filter the data depending on the parameters.

```
final FutureProvider<List<Card>> readAllCardProvider =
    FutureProvider<List<Card>>(
  (FutureProviderRef<List<Card>> ref) async {
    final CardUtil cardUtil = await ref.watch(cardUtilProvider.future);
    return cardUtil.readAll();
  },
);
```

I have also tried out sending a `Map` instead of the Card type as the parameter to the Family but didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<Card>` is not a suitable type for a family identifier for RiverPod.  As the docs say in https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family#passing-multiple-parameters-to-a-family

> Families have no built-in support for passing multiple values to a provider.
>
> On the other hand, that value could be anything (as long as it matches with the restrictions mentioned previously).
>
> This includes:
>
> - A tuple from tuple
> - Objects generated with Freezed or built_value
> - Objects using equatable

A `List<Card>` does not have a deep equality for ==, and therefore no two evaluations will show the same family provider.

Or, you can use a generated provider with a more robust family identifier strategy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew about this so I assumed Map was a good alternative (my bad!) and used it as well. Tuple did the job for me!